# Use axios data and declaration using destruction assignment

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I read a project fulfilled to learn architecture recently.
Below is the  backend data:
/data/product.js

```
const products = [
  {
    _id:'1',
    name: 'Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones',
    image: '/images/airpods.jpg',
    description:
      'Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-quality AAC audio offers immersive listening experience Built-in microphone allows you to take calls while working',
    brand: 'Apple',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 89.99,
    countInStock: 3,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  },
  {
    _id:'2',
    name: 'iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Memory',
    image: '/images/phone.jpg',
    description:
      'Introducing the iPhone 11 Pro. A transformative triple-camera system that adds tons of capability without complexity. An unprecedented leap in battery life',
    brand: 'Apple',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 599.99,
    countInStock: 60,
    rating: 4.0,
    numReviews: 4,
  },
  {
    _id: '3',

    name: 'Cannon EOS 80D DSLR Camera',
    image: '/images/camera.jpg',
    description:
      'Characterized by versatile imaging specs, the Canon EOS 80D further clarifies itself using a pair of robust focusing systems and an intuitive design',
    brand: 'Cannon',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 929.99,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  },
  {
    _id:'4',
    name: 'Sony Playstation 4 Pro White Version',
    image: '/images/playstation.jpg',
    description:
      'The ultimate home entertainment center starts with PlayStation. Whether you are into gaming, HD movies, television, music',
    brand: 'Sony',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 399.99,
    countInStock: 10,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  },
  {
    _id:'5',
    name: 'Logitech G-Series Gaming Mouse',
    image: '/images/mouse.jpg',
    description:
      'Get a better handle on your games with this Logitech LIGHTSYNC gaming mouse. The six programmable buttons allow customization for a smooth playing experience',
    brand: 'Logitech',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 49.99,
    countInStock: 7,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  },
  {
    _id:'6',
    name: 'Amazon Echo Dot 3rd Generation',
    image: '/images/alexa.jpg',
    description:
      'Meet Echo Dot - Our most popular smart speaker with a fabric design. It is our most compact smart speaker that fits perfectly into small space',
    brand: 'Amazon',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 29.99,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 0,
    numReviews: 0,
  },
]

 module.exports= products
```

Below is backend server:
server.js

```
onst express = require('express')
const app = express()
const products =require('./data/products')
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running')
})

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    res.json(products)
})
app.listen(5000,console.log('Server running on port 5000'))
```

Below is the rawdata while I open server on port 5000:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"1",
      "name":"Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
      "image":"/images/airpods.jpg",
      "description":"Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-quality AAC audio offers immersive listening experience Built-in microphone allows you to take calls while working",
      "brand":"Apple",
      "category":"Electronics",
      "price":89.99,
      "countInStock":3,
      "rating":0,
      "numReviews":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"2",
      "name":"iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Memory",
      "image":"/images/phone.jpg",
      "description":"Introducing the iPhone 11 Pro. A transformative triple-camera system that adds tons of capability without complexity. An unprecedented leap in battery life",
      "brand":"Apple",
      "category":"Electronics",
      "price":599.99,
      "countInStock":60,
      "rating":4,
      "numReviews":4
   },
   {
      "_id":"3",
      "name":"Cannon EOS 80D DSLR Camera",
      "image":"/images/camera.jpg",
      "description":"Characterized by versatile imaging specs, the Canon EOS 80D further clarifies itself using a pair of robust focusing systems and an intuitive design",
      "brand":"Cannon",
      "category":"Electronics",
      "price":929.99,
      "countInStock":0,
      "rating":0,
      "numReviews":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"4",
      "name":"Sony Playstation 4 Pro White Version",
      "image":"/images/playstation.jpg",
      "description":"The ultimate home entertainment center starts with PlayStation. Whether you are into gaming, HD movies, television, music",
      "brand":"Sony",
      "category":"Electronics",
      "price":399.99,
      "countInStock":10,
      "rating":0,
      "numReviews":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"5",
      "name":"Logitech G-Series Gaming Mouse",
      "image":"/images/mouse.jpg",
      "description":"Get a better handle on your games with this Logitech LIGHTSYNC gaming mouse. The six programmable buttons allow customization for a smooth playing experience",
      "brand":"Logitech",
      "category":"Electronics",
      "price":49.99,
      "countInStock":7,
      "rating":0,
      "numReviews":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"6",
      "name":"Amazon Echo Dot 3rd Generation",
      "image":"/images/alexa.jpg",
      "description":"Meet Echo Dot - Our most popular smart speaker with a fabric design. It is our most compact smart speaker that fits perfectly into small space",
      "brand":"Amazon",
      "category":"Electronics",
      "price":29.99,
      "countInStock":0,
      "rating":0,
      "numReviews":0
   }
]
```

Below is one snippet of frontend to request the data using destruction assignment syntax which works well in the project.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/products')
      setProducts(data)
    }
    fetchProducts()
  },[])
```

I do not know the array of objects could be assigned,so I mock it like below,but undefined,in up project snippet,the data could be successfully fetched from back end and used,why?

```
const products=[{"_id":"1"},{"_id":"2"}];
const {data}=products;
console.log(data);
```

Comment: No, it can't. But see the *axios* documentation about what the promise fulfills with - it's not just the data itself, it's a response object with a `.data` property.

Comment: It might also help the understanding to change the `fetchProducts` effect to do `const response = await axios.get('/products'); console.log(response); setProducts(response.data);`

Comment: hello,I screen axois document too,but did not find what you talked about.Can you throw a link or something like that?

Comment: Why use a huge http library when fetch isn't that complicated? `const data = await fetch('/products').then(res => res.json())`

Comment: axios could be used in nodejs but fetch can not be.

Comment: @juexu https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Comment: @Bergi,thanks,your answer help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

axios-http.com/docs/res_schema ,as the links shows,axios will return a schema different with `fetch` Api